# Übersetzung eines russischen Idioms, Wortlaut “Du bist ja eine Schatulle mit doppeltem Boden!”

Tags: idiom, russian-to-german

Ist es fürs deutsche Ohr verständlich, wenn man sagt "Du bist ja eine Schatulle mit doppeltem Boden!" und dabei meint, dass jemand komplexer ist, als zunächst vermutet? Es geht um die Übersetzung der folgenden Passage:

*- Was weißt du über Drachen?*

*- Vor einem Jahr hielt ich Drachen für nicht existent.*

*Eine klare, prägnante, lakonische Antwort. Sehr gut, Titus der Schwätzer, du kannst dich ja doch kurz fassen… Stopp. Irgendwas stimmt nicht. Titus der Schwätzer hätte gesagt: „Vor einem Jahr habe ich gedacht, dass es keine Drachen gibt“. **Du bist ja eine Schatulle mit doppeltem Boden,** Titus der Schwätzer.*

Im Russischen ist dies kein gebräuchliches Idiom, die Bedeutung ergibt sich allerdings aus dem Kontext. Ist das im Deutschen auch der Fall?

Answer (score 4):

"Schatulle mit doppeltem Boden" ist im Deutschen nicht üblich, allenfalls "Koffer mit doppeltem Boden".

Im Kontext der Übersetzung könnte man auch einfach "Du überraschst mich" oder "Du zeigst ja ungeahnte Seiten" sagen.

**Update:**

Man könnte auch "Schatulle / Kästchen / Truhe mit Geheimfach" sagen.

*Bemerkung:*

Obwohl nicht Gegenstand der Frage, möchte ich noch die Redewendung "Titus der Schwätzer" kommentieren. Diese eignet sich, um **über jemanden zu sprechen** (d.h. um Titus das Attribut *Schwätzer* zu verleihen), aber nicht, um jemanden **anzusprechen**. Ich würde als Anrede folgendes bevorzugen:

- Titus Du Schwätzer
- schwatzhafter Titus

Eine Alternative, die sich als Anrede eignet, ist "Titus [Schwatzmaul](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schwatzmaul)".

Comment: Vielen Dank, auch für die Bemerkung! Gleich dazu: Es klingt für mich ähnlich gebaut wie "Alexander der Große". Tatsächlich taucht es auch nicht in einer direkten Ansprache auf. Im obigen Abschnitt sind nur die mit einem "-" Strich gekennzeichneten Zeilen gesprochen, der Abschnitt danach sind Gedanken des Protagonisten, die nicht gesprochen sondern gedacht sind. Ist unter diesen Umständen "Titus der Schwätzer" geeignet?

Comment: @Photon Es handelt sich in beiden Fällen um einen sog.  [Beinamen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beiname).  Der Satz "Sehr gut, Titus der Schwätzer, du kannst dich ja doch kurz fassen…" klingt merkwürdog, auch wenn er nur einen Gedanken ausdrückt und nicht wirklich der Anrede dient.  Ich würde an dieser Stelle einfach nur "Titus" schreiben.

Comment: Mein Vorschlag: *Eine klare, prägnante, lakonische Antwort. Sehr gut, Titus,, du kannst dich ja doch kurz fassen… Stopp. Irgendwas stimmt nicht. Titus der Schwätzer hätte gesagt: „Vor einem Jahr habe ich gedacht, dass es keine Drachen gibt“. Du zeigst ja ungeahnte Seiten, Titus.*

Comment: @PaulFrost: "Du zeigst ja ungeahnte Seiten" ist geeignet, wenn es auf normales Deutsch übersetzt werden soll. Ist es ein Märchen, das geheimnisvoll, mystisch oder lyrisch klingen soll, wäre "du bist ja eine Schatulle mit doppeltem Boden" sinnvoller. Es kommt also auf den Kontext an, was man hier am besten als Übertragung verwendet.

Comment: Ich kann sehr gerne meinen aktuellen Übersetzungsfortschritt verlinken, damit der Textstil klarer wird (das Original steht auch frei im Netz, also sollte das kein Problem sein), aber die Benimmregeln hier raten davon ab, deswegen bin ich da eher vorsichtig.

Comment: @äüö Ich habe noch ein Update gemacht.

Comment: "Titus Schwatzmaul" ist super, den nehm ich, vielen Dank für den Vorschlag!

Comment: Jetzt kommt mir allerdings: Wie würde man auf diese Art "Titus der Bücherwurm" und "Titus der Senator" umformen? Und, Verzeihung, "Sam der Scheißer"... :) Es sind alles Spitznamen, mit denen sich Dorfbewohner in einer feudalen Gesellschaft einer Alternativ-Erde gegenseitig versehen.

Comment: Wenn es ein gemeinsames Muster geben soll, würde ich doch bei "xxx der yyy" bleiben. "Titus Bücherwurm" und "Sam Scheißer" ginge zur Not auch, aber "Titus Senator" nicht.

Comment: Uff, echt schade, "Titus der Senator" kommt nur an einer einzigen Stelle vor, "Titus der Schwätzer" aber häufiger... Wie wurden denn allgemein Spitznamen unter Dorfbewohnern gebildet, die den Vornamen angehängt wurden?

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass es eine allgemeine Regel zur Bildung von Spitznamen gibt. Wenn "Titus der Senator" nur an einer einzigen Stelle vorkommt, könnte das auch ein absichtlich anderes Schema haben, z.B.. "Herr Senator Titus" oder ironisch "Titus Dorfsenator".

Comment: Ah ja, das ist gut! Dann also im Allgemeinen "Titus Schwatzmaul" und "Sam Scheißer", aber an der einen Stelle mit "der": `- Sir Drache, seien Sie mir nicht böse, aber es ist nicht wahr, dass man in Büchern über Zauberei schreibt.  - Woher weißt du es denn, dass es nicht wahr ist, Titus der Bücherwurm? Oder Titus der Senator? Hast du es versucht?`

Comment: Da gibt es keine einfach Lösung. Es scheint, dass der Drache Titus anredet und ihn dabei in zwei möglichen Rollen sieht (Bücherwurm / Senator). Vielleicht würde folgendes passen: *Woher weißt du es denn, dass es nicht wahr ist, Titus Bücherwurm? Oder soll ich Dich als Titus den Senator anreden? Hast du es versucht?*

Comment: Noch ein Vorschlag: *Woher weißt du denn, dass es nicht wahr ist? Du, Titus der Bücherwurm? Oder du, Titus der Senator?*

Answer (score 2):

Ja. "Schatulle mit doppeltem Boden" ist kein festes Idiom im Deutschen. Seine Bedeutung ergibt sich aus dem Kontext.

Es ist meiner Meinung nach eine lustige Formulierung. Um zu genau Deiner Interpretation und nicht nur etwas Wagem grob in die Richtung zu kommen, bräuchte ich wohl noch etwas mehr Kontext - aber der würde sich beim Lesen des Buches sicher ergeben.

Comment: Lustig darf sie ruhig sein, der Originaltext ist insgesamt mit viel Humor geschrieben und der Autor spielt häufig mit der Sprache. Weiterer Kontext würde, glaube ich, zum Verständnis dieser Formulierung nicht beitragen, entweder es klappt mit dem Ausschnitt oder nicht... Aber das klingt ja zumindest vorsichtig optimistisch, ich hatte befürchtet, die Formulierung würde im Deutschen völlig schief klingen!

Comment: @Photon: nein, klingt völlig in Ordnung im Deutschen und ist ein schönes Bild mit selbsterklärender Aussage (*thumbsup*)

Answer (score 1):

Das ist verständlich, [doppelbödig](https://www.dwds.de/wb/doppelb%C3%B6dig) als Adjektiv ist allerdings eher negativ konnotiert. Die etablierte deutsche Redewendung bei Personen ist:

> Stille Wasser sind tief

siehe beispielsweise [hier](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=Stille%20Wasser%20sind%20tief&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou).

Comment: Danke! Diese Redewendung ist mir bekannt, allerdings ist Titus der Schwätzer -- wie der Name schon sagt -- keine stille und introvertierte Person. Die Überraschung des Protagonisten gilt umgekehrt der Tatsache, dass Titus plötzlich von seinem Redeschwall abrückt und eine präzise Antwort gibt.